# defaultView agendaWeek to hide month header

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a calendar using the plugin full-calendar. For default, in the table header (fc-widget-header), the current month shown (fc-day-header). I want hide the month and display only the day of the week.

I can not find the property that disables the month, also i need to remove the character (/).

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    hiddenDays: [0],        
    dayNamesShort:
        ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],            
    axisFormat: 'H:mm',
    timeFormat: {
        agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'
    },      
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events
});
```

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for something like [columnFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/columnFormat/).

To achieve the desired effect set the `columnFormat` like this

`columnFormat: 'ddd D'`

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdmr0hx4/2/)**

Comment: one thing i have seen, the format is correct, but the day of the week is not correct. If  i remove the property columnFormat, the day of the week looks good. Today is 14 but if i remove the property columnFormat will show 3.

Comment: Now ok, the issue is resolved, this is the format: columnFormat: 'ddd D',